# sqlalchemy - Execute plain text (don't bind parameters)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert some rows into a database table using SQLAlchemy, but some of the rows contain strings that SQLAlchemy interprets as parameters. That causes errors, even though I just want to insert the strings exactly as they are.

For example, one entry is like:

> abc, \“depth\“:0,

The query it is supposed to execute is:

> INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES ( 'abc, \“depth\“:0,')

(I realize that I need to change the \" into double-backslashes for the database to interpret it correctly.)

Which causes the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter '0' [SQL: "INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES ( 'abc, \“depth\“%(0)s,')\n"] [parameters: [{}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)

Is there a way to have SQLAlchemy insert the string as-is (without modifying it or trying to interpret it)?

Thanks.

Essentially, the code is:

```
engine = create_engine(...)
session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
query = """INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES ( 'abc, \“depth\“:0,')"""
session.execute(query)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

But the query is created programmatically in a loop of thousands of strings (and there will be new strings every day), so I don't have pre-existing knowledge of what every string is.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text, escape the colon with a backslash, if using the `text()` wrapper. If not, it should work, unless you're using `Session.execute()`. In other words: please produce a [mcve].

Comment: How are the strings generated? Could you not actually generate the value to insert, without the surrounding statement, and pass that to an insert using placeholders?